# View PostScript documents in iOS?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, postscript

I am looking for a way to view PostScript files in iOS. It appears that there's no built-in mechanism in iOS for the same. Also, I'm unable to find any viewer app on the App Store.

While Safari for macOS supports viewing it, iOS version doesn't appear to do so. Is there any app that renders postscript as opposed to showing the text file?

Comment: PostScript files are text files. We have a software recommendation tag and [meta post on how to ask for software recommendations](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/5472) if that's what you seek here.

Comment: Thanks @bmike.  Yes, that's what I want, unless there's an app-free way to do it, which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS Dropbox app renders PostScript files in its file browser and viewing panel, exactly as for PDFs or other image formats.

Comment: Officially it only displays eps files, but renaming my .ps file to .eps made it work.  The other answers probably work, but I don't want to use a website, and I tend to avoid Google products, so I'm marking this as the answer for me.

Comment: .ps files worked for me without having to change the extension to .eps.

Comment: Interesting.  Well, it's good to have the tip here in case someone else has my issue.  Maybe different versions of Dropbox, or different plans (I have the free plan), or different iOS versions?  I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive – online backup iOS apps supports viewing PostScript files. It is a universal app available for both iPad and iPhone.

[image]

Download Google Drive app from the App Store using the following link:

- https://itunes.apple.com/app/google-drive-online-backup/id507874739

Comment: Unfortunately, the Google drive app doesn't appear to be able to save the ps files in pdf or other usable/viewable formats, though it will display them in its viewing pane.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to [this site](http://www.docspal.com/viewer) and read the file using your browser. There is also an option to convert files to a different format.